# Are there any perks/discounts for travelling as a couple on Air France?

Tags: air-travel, france, air-france

When booking a ticket on [Air France](http://www.airfrance.us/cgi-bin/AF/US/en/local/resainfovol/achat/RechercherAction.do) there is a mention of special fares when travelling as a couple, but I haven't seen anything that specifically calls out fares as being a "couples" fare. Is anyone familiar with this?

> When traveling as a couple or with children in metropolitan France,
>   you can take advantage of special fares. Proof of relationship will be
>   requested at boarding. Please consult the eligibility conditions
>   listed below.

Comment: Looks like it only applies for domestic flights though, are you definitely looking at those rather than international ones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used this special fare on domestic flights (Toulouse-Paris and Nantes-Lyon).

I didn't use your link, but the obvious french http://www.airfrance.fr/

When I select two passengers, I am asked if I qualify for couple fare. I answer yes and then all the suggested flights get the special fare.

EDIT: I just tried Toulouse-New York. No special fare is offered.